# Convert string to IP address format

Tags: c#, string.format

I'm reading IP address numbers from database in a int format but I want to show them
in IP format like 000.000.000.000

Is it possible using the String.Format method?

For e.g.:

```
string str = String.Format("{0:#,###,###.##}", ips);
```

Comment: what language and what is your ips an array of ints or just one big number. Give an example of ips.

Answer (score 13):

If you use the IPAddress object in the System.Net namespace to parse your address in as follows:

```
IPAddress ip = IPAddress.Parse(IPStringHere);
```

then use the "ToString()" method on that object:

```
string outputString = ip.ToString();
```

you can get a string that shows the IP address provided in the format you require using integers and full stops.

The IPAddress parsing routine will take a string IP address and it will also take an int/long int format address too allowing you to parse both formats.

As a bonus if your use "TryParse" and put your conversion in an if block, you can also test to see if the input format results in a correct IP address before returning the string, handy for input validation.

Comment: You know that the answer has nothing to do with the question right? I know 4 years too late but it is still not an answer to the question.

Comment: Down-vote because all this does is convert a string to an IP address structure, the OP explicitly asked for a string format output in order to display the IP address (Exactly the same reason I ended up here through google)

Comment: Down-vote removed and I edited the question instead.

Answer (score 2):

Are these 32-bit integers that each represent the entire IP address? If so...

```
IPAddress ip = new IPAddress((long)ips);
return ip.ToString();
```

(I don't know why that constructor takes a long, it'll throw an exception if you exceed the range of a UInt32, so a UInt32 would be more appropriate in my opinion.)

Comment: Using the `Usomething` (or their alias `usomething` like `uint`) types is frowned in .NET. It isn't CLS compliamnt, because some languages don't distinguish between signed and unsigned (and have only, normally, the signed version). `IPAddress` is a .NET framework class, so it must be compatible with all the languages, so no `UInt32` and yes to `long`

Answer (score 2):

I came looking for the same answer .. but seeing as there are non I write my self.

```
private string padIP(string ip)
{
    string output = string.Empty;
    string[] parts = ip.Split('.');
    for (int i = 0; i < parts.Length; i++)
    {
        output += parts[i].PadLeft(3, '0');
        if (i != parts.Length - 1)
            output += ".";
    }
    return output;
}
```

edit: ah i see in int format .. never mind, not sure how you would do that....

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?
**.Net 4.0**

```
string str = string.Join(".", ips.Select(x => x.ToString()))
```

**Earlier**

```
string str = string.Join(".", ips.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray())
```

This says, join a `string[]` with `.` in between. The array is made up of ips, converted to string using `ToString()` and turned into a string[] using `ToArray()`

Comment: IN C# 4.0 they added a IEnumerable version of join, so you can delete the "ToArray()".

Comment: nice! i'll update with both version, OP didnt specify which version of .net

Answer (score 0):

If it's an array:

```
string str = String.Format("{0:###}.{1:###}.{2:###}.{3:###}", ips[0], ips[1], ips[2], ips[3]);
```

Comment: but i need to add dot with a single return(nvarchar type) of query's output like 111111111111 to

Comment: What type is your ips? Is it an array of `int`, or is it a string or what?

Comment: m not using any array there for just reading data from reader like string ips = dr["block_ip"].ToString();
string  str = String.Format("{0:#,###,###.##}",ips);

Comment: If your string isn't already formatted, it's impossible to divide it. How could I know if 11111 is 1.1.1.11 or 1.1.11.1? And what was dr["block_ip"] before you ToString() it?